# "Écriture inclusive" and official formatting

Tags: genre, écriture-inclusive

I know that the topic is quite burning in France these years, yet I'm currently writing official documents (agreements, contracts, charters) and I need specific rules to proceed.

These agreements mention parties that are named "le Salarié", "le Client", "l'Auteur". Examples:

> "Le Salarié s'engage à respecter les conditions suivantes :
>
> - Il doit faire ceci, cela..."

Shall I include feminine desambiguation in these documents? All across the document, which can be heavy? and with which format?

- Il/Elle, le/la Salarié/e
- Il(Elle), le(la) Salarié(e)
- Il·Elle; le·a Salarié·e

Can I mention that "le Salarié" does not withstand gender of contractor?

Comment: Does the organization for which you work has guidelines on this topic that you can rely on?

Comment: Not really. It does have a specific lobby to promote female equality (it's a company in IT); yet there's no specific guideline (explicit or implicit)

Comment: Do you have access to examples of previous contracts written in French by your organization then?

Comment: @Sacha yes, indeed, there is no inclusion in it. "le Salarié / il" is anytime used. However, document has been created many years ago; first author didn't had such interrogations.

Comment: In my opinion, being the first to use inclusive writting could be viewed as a militant action while keeping the status quo would be viewed as neutral.
If at some time your organization decides that inclusive writting should be used, that should not come from someone just wanting to write a contract.
Inclusive writting is a topic with no consensus and very hard reactions from both 'sides', I would not want to bring this topic in when just wanting to do me job.

Comment: @Toto : sorry but in documents, first letters of defined parties are capitalized. https://e2f.com/952/ . I rollbacked your edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend following your organization's guidelines, if any, or to follow your organization's usual way of writting documents.

As you noticed, this topic can be considered difficult, especially for some people or contexts which can lead to very hard reactions either from people in favor or against its use.
Also, there is no consensus about its use.

Being the first one to use inclusive writting in your work documents can be viewed as a militant action while keeping the status quo would come out as more neutral.
If one day your organization decides that inclusive writting should be used, it should come from the relevant people.

Answer (score 1):

Au sein d'une entreprise privée, c'est une décision qui ne saurait incomber au seul rédacteur. Les parties prenantes possibles sont (sans revendiquer l'exhaustivité):

- le patron,
- le service juridique,
- le service de communication,
- le service pour la promotion de l'égalité ou pour la prévention des discriminations, souvent rattaché au...
- ...service des ressources humaines, qui à son tour peut solliciter...
- ...les instances de représentation du personnel.

Le statu quo me semble la solution la plus sage pour que les documents soient achevés dans les temps.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed by other people, see with you hierarchy what the guidelines are if you want to use the point médian •.

A workaround I tend to use and which I suggest to you is using sentence constructions that do not reveal the gender.

For instance, you can use "La personne salariée" and go on with using feminine agreement.